# Looping through data frames in global environment and passing a function to all to create new list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, loops

I have 125 89x89 dataframes in my global environment and need to turn each into a into 1 x 7921 (i.e., 89^2) dataframe and then bind them into a single 125 x 7921 DataFrame. I'm having success getting the dataframes from independent objects in the global environment into a list using `mget`:

For example,

```
dfs_list <- Filter(function(x) is(x, "data.frame"), mget(ls()))
```

returns a list of 125 89x89 dataframes in `df_list`.

Where I might be messing up and where I've struggled the most is writing a function for the lapply call. I'm trying to use

`list1 <- lapply(mget(ls()), f1)`

where f1 is the function I need to call to transform the data from long to wide for each DataFrame.

The function I am trying to use is

```
f1 <- function(data.frame) {
   . %>%
   dplyr::mutate(dplyr::mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
   tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = row, values_from = -row)
}
```

which stems from a previous question I asked here. The code within the function works perfectly when I pass just one DataFrame at a time, but seeing as this is a large dataset that is going to continue to expand and need to be pivoted, it would be nice to have a function to automate the process.

The output of running `list1 <- lapply(mget(ls()), f1)` on the objects in my global environment is a list of 125 functions. What I am trying to get is an output list length of 125 with the wide dataframes.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: By the way, how did get 125 data frames in global environment? You should be saving such similarly structured objects in a list. See this [canonical R answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/1422451), advising: *Don't ever create `d1` `d2` `d3`, ..., `dn` in the first place. Create a list `d` with `n` elements.*

Comment: @Parfait that's embarrassing .. lol. Thanks for the advice -- worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out the issue was with my function `f1` and `mget(ls())` in `lapply`. Here's what worked to solve the problem:

A

```
dfs_list <- Filter(function(x) is(x, "data.frame"), mget(ls()))
```

B

```
f1 <- function(df) { 
   df %>% 
     dplyr::mutate(dplyr::mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
     tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = row, values_from = -row)
}
```

C

```
lst1 <- lapply(dfs_list, f1)
```